# Evaluation of limit

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{ x\to 0}x(\frac{1}{e}-(\frac{x}{1+x})^x)$$

How to proceed after applying LH rule once.

Comment: Would it be that hard to type your question instead of posting an image? Please see [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It actually helps searching to have the question typed as search algorithm has no idea what image says.

Answer (score 6):

L'Hospital's rule is *not* the alpha and omega of limits computation. You just have to use *Taylor's formula* at order $2$.

First a change of variable: set $u=\dfrac1x$; $\;u\to 0\;$  as $x\to\infty$. Now
\begin{align}\ln\Bigl(\frac{x}{1+x}\Bigr)^x&=x\ln\frac{x}{1+x}=\frac1u\ln\frac{1}{1+u}=\frac{-\ln(1+u)}{u}\\
&=\frac{-u+\dfrac{u^2}2+o(u^2)}u=-1+\frac u2+o(u).
\end{align}
Thus we have
$$\Bigl(\frac{x}{1+x}\Bigr)^x=\mathrm e^{x\ln\!\tfrac{x}{1+x}}=\mathrm e^{-1+\tfrac u2+o(u)}=\frac{e^{\tfrac u2+o(u)}}{\mathrm e}=\frac{1+\dfrac u2+o(u)}{\mathrm e}=\frac 1e+\frac{u}{2\mathrm e}+o(u),$$
so
$$x\biggl(\frac 1e-\Bigl(\frac{x}{1+x}\Bigr)^x\biggr)=\frac{-\dfrac{u}{2\mathrm e}+o(u)}{u}=-\dfrac1{2\mathrm e}+o(1)\to-\dfrac1{2\mathrm e}. $$

Comment: Sometimes, in fact, it is the iota of limit computation.